# BxSlider in small res issue - wrong slide loading after control left/right

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bxslider

I have simple bx-slider [here](http://rubyfish.devel.hatimeria.com/). After shrink browser window to small size like 360 slides in recentSoldCarousel act strange. When you click on left/right control you can see correct slide and after that slide blink and another - wrong slide is loading.
Here is my code:

```
$('#recentSoldCarousel .carousel-inner').bxSlider({
    slideWidth: 247,
    minSlides: 1,
    maxSlides: 3,
    moveSlides: 3,
    pager: false,
    slideMargin: 10,
    startSlide: 0,
    touchEnabled: true,
    oneToOneTouch: true,
    preventDefaultSwipeX: true,
    preventDefaultSwipeY: true,
    autoDirection: 'next',
});
```

I'm newbe in jQuery so if anybody can help me i will be very gratefull.

Comment: For me it works the same way as it does in other resolutions..
Your slider has the same data in every slide.. then how to we know whether its working fine or not.. can you provide a http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Thank you for answer. Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yeD3C/